# Trouble with Sqlite on Python/Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to learn Django and following along the Django Book tutorial and I'm getting an error when I type these lines into the Python shell:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Here's the traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 306,
 in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
288, in _cursor
    self._sqlite_create_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
278, in _sqlite_create_connection
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? On my settings.py I have `DATABASES ENGINE` set to: `django.db.backends.sqlite3` and `NAME` set to: `C:\Python27/PythonProjects/mysite`. Thanks!

Comment: Don't mix `/` and `\` in a path, try using *one* type of slash only.

Comment: Well, I changed it all to "/" on my path and i'm still getting the same operational error message

Comment: is `mysite` a directory perhaps? Use a path to a database name.

Comment: Alternatively, make it a relative path: `./mysite.db`.

Comment: Yes it is a directory. It's my first time with databases and Django. I only have 1 database(.db) file in my computer that's called 185test.db located in my C:/Python27/Lib/test, could this be it?

Comment: the file will be created the first time the site is started. I doubt that `185test.db` is the file you need if you haven't started Django before.

Answer (score 1):

I find (in modern Django) that just giving a filename like `database.sqlite` for the filename as the name is the best option. Django should interpret that by sticking the new database in the root folder of the project, which is perfect for my needs.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Oli :D, thanks for your help too Martjin!